# MySQL - How to change value in column?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, opencart

I have a OpenCart store with more than 23000 products and I need to change one option (Requeres Shipping) for all of my products. I need to change that option in my database. I have a table `n0v_product` with with column `shipping` with value 0. I need to change `shipping` value to 1 for all products. How to update the value in the column with phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 14):

Run this in a test database before running it on production but this should do the job.

```
UPDATE n0v_product 
SET shipping = '1' 
WHERE shipping = '0'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) command to change all values on column `shipping` to `1` on `n0v_product`:

```
UPDATE `n0v_product` SET `shipping` = 1
```

If you only want to set the value if `shipping` is `0` you can use the following:

```
UPDATE `n0v_product` SET `shipping` = 1 WHERE `shipping` = 0
```

---

You should check the rows before `UPDATE` to make sure you really want to `UPDATE` these rows:

```
-- all rows of table n0v_product
SELECT `shipping`, * FROM `n0v_product`

-- only rows with shipping = 0
SELECT `shipping`, * FROM `n0v_product` WHERE `shipping` = 0
```